# Error 404 but not if I click on it

Tags: html, hyperlink, web, http-status-code-404

If I go to for example www.example.com(requires log in(I log in)) and it has a list of links.

I click on one of them and it redirects me to a fully working page. But if I copy the url (of the link) and paste it into my browser I will get a 404 message. How is this possible and why?

Does it have something to do with cookies? I have no idea.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some server variables for credential and/or in-favorite that are created when you login to a site. You can not expect to view the same facility while you are not logged in.

Comment: See I am accessing the links with login information?

Comment: Thats true, most probably there are some background redirect or page search based on your login credentials.